# Как вставить запись если её нет при обновлении данных (postgresql аналог replace mysql)?

Tags: postgresql

Вот есть запрос UPDATE, как его переписать, чтобы если в базе нет записи с этим id, она была создана. Аналог replace или on duplicate key update

```
UPDATE directories_struct SET html=$1::text,css=$2::text WHERE id=$3::int
```

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/264281/

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO directories_struct (id, html, css)
VALUES ($3::int, $1::text, $2::text)
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET
html=$1::text,css=$2::text;
```